# How can we customize Wordpress coding standards and use them in VSCode?

Tags: php, wordpress, visual-studio-code, phpcodesniffer

How can we customize [Wordpress coding standards](https://github.com/WordPress-Coding-Standards/WordPress-Coding-Standards) on Windows and use them with VSCode? 
I am trying to do this globally so I don't have to do it for every project (I don't think currently that this is a bad idea?) but I guess the same thing can be applied to local project, only paths should be changed.

First, I have installed them in `C:\wamp64\www\_standards\wpcs` and I have set correct path using:

```
phpcs --config-set installed_paths C:\wamp64\www\_standards\wpcs
```

Now when I do `phpcs -i` I can see that WordPress standards are installed

```
The installed coding standards are MySource, PEAR, PSR1, PSR12, PSR2, Squiz, Zend, WordPress, WordPress-Core, WordPress-Docs, WordPress-Extra and WordPress-VIP
```

and in VSCode User Settings I did

```
"phpcs.enable": true,
"phpcs.standard": "WordPress"
```

So far everything seems to be working nicely. Now, how do I customize them and disable few things, like `Spaces must be used to indent lines; tabs are not allowed`?

There is something written [about using custom rules](https://github.com/WordPress-Coding-Standards/WordPress-Coding-Standards#using-a-custom-ruleset) and [here is their sample file](https://github.com/WordPress-Coding-Standards/WordPress-Coding-Standards/blob/develop/phpcs.xml.dist.sample), so I created `C:\wamp64\www\_standards\phpcs.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="Custom">

     <!-- Enable colors in report -->
     <arg name="colors"/>

     <!-- Add source codes in the report -->
     <arg value="s"/>

     <!-- Load WordPress Coding standards -->
     <rule ref="WordPress"/>

     <!-- Customize -->
     <rule ref="WordPress">
          <exclude name="Generic.WhiteSpace.DisallowSpaceIndent.SpacesUsed" />
     </rule>

</ruleset>
```

This way nothing shows up after I do `phpcs -i` (not even WordPress standards show up)

```
phpcs --config-set installed_paths C:\wamp64\www\_posao\_standards\wpcs,C:\wamp64\www\_posao\_standards
```

But, if I rename `phpcs.xml` to `ruleset.xml` and I repeat previous code for installing paths I get this

```
The installed coding standards are MySource, PEAR, PSR1, PSR12, PSR2, Squiz, Zend, WordPress, WordPress-Core, WordPress-Docs, WordPress-Extra, WordPress-VIP and _standards
```

So I changed User Settings in VSCode

```
phpcs.standard": "_standards"
```

Now, how do I rename this `_standards` to a better name and how do I load WordPress standards first and overwrite it with custom rules? Because contents of file, if they are even loaded, aren't used - I still get `Spaces must be used to indent lines; tabs are not allowed` when I manually call `phpcs page.php`.

EDIT: So, since I had WPCS installed outside of projects with config-set already pointing to that folder, I have placed only `phpcs.xml` file inside Wordpress theme and now I can manually call `phpcs page.php` - it works nice. But now is the problem that I can't set it in VSCode so that it automatically runs after saving file?

Comment: Note that you don't need to install an XML file like you did as you haven't written any custom sniff classes. You can just use the full path to the file as the "standard" argument. E.g., `phpcs --standard=/path/to/ruleset.xml ...`. Hopefully, you can just type that path into VSCode as the `standard` and it would work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of pointers:

- The `phpcs.xml` file (can also be `phpcs.xml.dist` and other similar variations that have a preferred order) (not `ruleset.xml`), should be in the root of your *project* code, not in the directory you installed WPCS.
- The VS Code config would then be the path (absolute or relative) to that `phpcs.xml` file:

  `"phpcs.standard": "/path/to/project/phpcs.xml"`

  or

  `"phpcs.standard": "./phpcs.xml"`

You'll still need to ensure that the `phpcs` executable you're referring to has got the `WordPress` standards registered.

Reference: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ikappas.phpcs

Answer (score 0):

I enabled WordPress Coding Standards (WPCS) after a long searching and try-outs. Here's what I did in a *Windows 10 (Home)* machine.

> Please note, I activated WPCS only in Visual Studio Code, and not in project scope using `composer.json` and `./vendor/`

Steps I followed:

1. In cmd or git bash run `composer global require "squizlabs/php_codesniffer=*"`

The installation path would be:

> `C:\Users\{YOUR USER}\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin`

1. Install the phpcs VSCode Extension (by Ioannis Kappas)
2. In VSCode, File » Preferences » Settings (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>)
3. Search "phpcs"
4. Now in **Phpcs: Executable Path** put: `C:\Users\{YOUR USER}\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin\phpcs` (don't forget to add `phpcs` at the tail)
5. Somewhere in your computer, create a directory for storing WordPress Coding Standards (eg. `coding-standards`) (ref: [tommcfarlin](https://github.com/tommcfarlin/phpcs-wpcs-vscode))
6. Inside the directory (eg. `coding-standards/`) run the command: `composer create-project wp-coding-standards/wpcs:dev-master --no-dev`
7. Open a command window and run: `C:/Users/{YOUR USER}/AppData/Roaming/Composer/vendor/bin/phpcs --config-set installed_paths H:/coding-standards/wpcs` (`H:/coding-standards/wpcs` would be your path, you did in step 6)

> The `installed_paths` is updated (overridden) in `C:\Users\{YOUR USER}\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\squizlabs\php_codesniffer\CodeSniffer.conf`. If your command in step 7 failed somehow, you can manually edit *this* file and add the path to the WPCS here.

8. Add a `phpcs.xml` or `phpcs.xml.dist` in your project root with content like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="YOURPROJECT">
    <config name="minimum_supported_wp_version" value="4.4.0" />
    <!-- <config name="testVersion" value="0.6-"/> -->

    <rule ref="WordPress-Core" />
    <rule ref="WordPress-Docs" />
    <rule ref="WordPress-Extra" />

    <rule ref="WordPress.WP.I18n">
        <properties>
            <property name="text_domain" type="array" value="your-text-domain" />
        </properties>
    </rule>

    <!-- Check all PHP files in directory tree by default. -->
    <arg name="extensions" value="php"/>
    <file>.</file>

    <exclude-pattern>/docker/*</exclude-pattern>
    <exclude-pattern>/node_modules/*</exclude-pattern>
    <exclude-pattern>/tests/*</exclude-pattern>
    <exclude-pattern>/vendor/*</exclude-pattern>
</ruleset>
```

> It's a template. Don't forget to update the `minimum_supported_wp_version` with your project's data. For a sample template, See [`phpcs.xml.dist.sample` - WordPress Coding Standard](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress-Coding-Standards/blob/develop/phpcs.xml.dist.sample)

9. If it's necessary, restart VSCode, and you are done